# Python concat pairs of tuples in a list

Tags: python, mysql, list, tuples

**I have a list of tuples that looks like this:**

```
l1 = [('X', 123, 456, 'a'), ('Y', 123, 456, 'b'), ('X', 123, 456, 'c'), ('Y', 123, 456, 'd')]
```

for each tuple, the first item alternates between 'X' and 'Y' only. 
The second and third item in the index are constants and the fourth item is a text value.

**i want to transform the list to this format:**

```
l1 = [(123, 456, 'a','b'),(123, 456, 'c','d')]
```

So for the text values of the X-Y adjacent tuple pairs, i combine them into 1 tuple while keeping the constants.

I do this because i want to insert my tuples into a MYSQL table which has this format:

```
id_1 id_2 X_text Y_text
123   456   a      b
123   456   c      d
```

how do i combine tuples in a list in a pairwise operation?

Comment: This looks like a simple loop. Have you tried anything?

Comment: You really should show us what you've tried, but it piqued my interest after recently looking at some `zip` questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
result = [l1[i][1: ] + (l1[i + 1][3], ) for i in xrange(0, len(l1), 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.  Essentially you need to step through the list in "twos", and then recompose the new list.

```
l1 = [('X', 123, 456, 'a'), ('Y', 123, 456, 'b'), ('X', 123, 456, 'c'), ('Y', 123, 456, 'd')]
l2 = []

for i in range(0, len(l1), 2):
    x = l1[i]
    y = l1[i+1]
    assert x[0] == 'X'
    assert y[0] == 'Y'
    assert x[1] == y[1]
    assert x[2] == y[2]
    l2.append((x[1], x[2], x[3], y[3]))

print l2
```

Please take note of the uses of assertions to assert your assumptions!

Output:

```
[(123, 456, 'a', 'b'), (123, 456, 'c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
  l1 = [('X', 123, 456, 'a'),
        ('Y', 123, 456, 'b'), 
        ('X', 123, 456, 'c'), 
        ('Y', 123, 456, 'd')]
  l1 =  tuple((x[1],x[2],x[3],l1[i+1][3]) for x,i in zip(l1,range(0,len(l1)-1)))
  l2 = (l1[0],l1[2]) #resulting tuple

  print l2
```